# CDK Fargate: Map subdomain to different container port

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

Look at the following CDK stack definition:

```
export class AwsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const myHostedZone = new route53.HostedZone(this, "HostedZone", {
      zoneName: domain,
    });

    const certificate = new acm.Certificate(this, "Certificate", {
      domainName: `*.${domain}`,
      validation: acm.CertificateValidation.fromDns(myHostedZone),
    });

    const image = new ecr.DockerImageAsset(this, "Image", { directory: "." });

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "ApplicationVpc", { maxAzs: 2 });

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "Cluster", {
      clusterName: "Cluster",
      vpc,
    });

    const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, "TaskDef");
    taskDefinition.addContainer("DefaultContainer", {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(image),
      portMappings: [
        { containerPort: 3000, hostPort: 3000 },
        { containerPort: 3001, hostPort: 3001 },
      ],
    });

    const service = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "Service", {
      cluster,
      publicLoadBalancer: true,
      taskDefinition,
      certificate,
    });

    service.loadBalancer.addRedirect()

    service.listener.addTargets("api", {
      priority: 10,
      conditions: [elb.ListenerCondition.hostHeaders([`api.${domain}`])],
      // what to do???
    });
  }
}
```

I want to map incoming traffic with `api.domain` to port 3001 and everything else should map to port 3000.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the following

```
export class AwsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const zone = new route53.HostedZone(this, "HostedZone", {
      zoneName: domain,
    });

    //const certificate = acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, "Certificate", certificateArn);

    const certificate = new acm.Certificate(this, "Certificate", {
      domainName: domain,
      subjectAlternativeNames: [`*.${domain}`],
      validation: acm.CertificateValidation.fromDns(zone),
    });

    const image = new ecr.DockerImageAsset(this, "Image", { directory: "." });

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "ApplicationVpc", { maxAzs: 2 });

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "Cluster", {
      clusterName: "Cluster",
      vpc,
    });

    const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, "TaskDef");
    taskDefinition.addContainer("DefaultContainer", {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(image),
      portMappings: [
        { containerPort: 3000, hostPort: 3000 },
        { containerPort: 3001, hostPort: 3001 },
      ],
      logging: new ecs.AwsLogDriver({
        streamPrefix: domain,
      }),
    });

    const service = new ecs.FargateService(this, "Service", {
      cluster,
      taskDefinition,
      assignPublicIp: true,
    });

    const lb = new elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "LoadBalancer", {
      vpc,
      internetFacing: true,
    });

    const listener = lb.addListener("Listener", {
      port: 443,
      certificates: [certificate],
    });

    listener.addTargets("API", {
      priority: 10,
      conditions: [elb.ListenerCondition.hostHeaders([`api.${domain}`])],
      port: 80,
      targets: [service.loadBalancerTarget({ containerName: "DefaultContainer", containerPort: 3001 })],
      healthCheck: {
        healthyHttpCodes: "200-399",
      },
    });

    listener.addTargets("UI", {
      port: 80,
      targets: [service.loadBalancerTarget({ containerName: "DefaultContainer", containerPort: 3000 })],
      healthCheck: {
        healthyHttpCodes: "200-399",
      },
    });

    new route53.ARecord(this, "AliasRecord", {
      zone,
      target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new alias.LoadBalancerTarget(lb)),
    });

    new route53.ARecord(this, "AliasRecordAPI", {
      recordName: `api.${domain}`,
      zone,
      target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new alias.LoadBalancerTarget(lb)),
    });
  }
}
```

I am still wondering why `listener.addTargets` requires port `80`.

Comment: Wow, seems like a lot of extra code that's not strictly relevant to the question. Did my answer not work for specifying a port for a subdomain?

Comment: @gshpychka no, did not work. I had to port 80 and containerPort 3000. could be a bug in the CDK

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: @gshpychka 50x error

Comment: Okay, I see. Interesting, thanks.

Comment: @gshpychka Did you ever try your solution?

Comment: I would if you had a minimally reproducible example in the question. I would require too much effort to set up and deploy without one.

Comment: Removed the answer since it didn't work.

Comment: @gshpychka my answer is kinda minimal because it contains all relevant pieces (SSL for example).

Comment: Yup, almost there. Add the container code, and wrap it in a CDK app and it'll be reproducible.